# C# for loop of two dimensional List

Tags: c#, list, loops

```
List<List<double>> A = new List<List<double>>()
{
    new List<double>() { 1, 0, 0 },
    new List<double>() { 1, -1, 0 }
};

List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < A[i].Count; j++)
     {
         if (A[i][j] != 0) 
         {
             Temm[i][j] = A[i][j]; 
         }
         else 
         { 
             Temm[i][j] = Temm[i][j - 1]; }
         }
     }
}
```

There is something wrong with this double for loop, I think `Temm[i][j]` maybe illegal, so what's the correct way ? I also wanted to know how to declare the given size of the two dimensional List

```
List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>
```

say
`Z * Y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. When you first start looping over an inner loop you should initialize the loop in that place in the output collection.
2. When you try to access [i][j] - to one that doesn't yet exist - which is everytime it will fail. Instead use the `Insert` method:

   ```
   List<List<double>> A = new List<List<double>>()
   {
       new List<double>() { 1, 0, 0 },
       new List<double>() { 1, -1, 0 }
   };    

   List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>(A.Count);
   for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
   {
       Temm.Insert(i,new List<double>());
       for (int j = 0; j < A[i].Count; j++)
       {
           if (A[i][j] != 0) { Temm[i].Insert(j,A[i][j]); }
           else { Temm[i].Insert(j,Temm[i][j - 1]); }
       }
   }
   ```

Because each time you insert to the end of the list I would prefer to use the `Add`:

```
List<List<double>> B = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
{
    List<double> innerResult = new List<double>();
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].Count; j++)
    {
        if (A[i][j] != 0)
        {
            innerResult.Add(A[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            innerResult.Add(innerResult[j - 1]);
        }
    }
    B.Add(innerResult);
}
```

Comment: so, `insert` couldn't replaced by `add`?

Comment: @user6703592 - They have 2 different functionalities. `Add` inserts in the end of the list. `Insert` does it a specific index. I personally prefer `Add` but because you use the `i` and `j` I used it to keep it as close to your syntax as possible

Comment: @user6703592 - Thanks for selecting my answer.

Comment: @user6703592 - for next time - don't immediately upvote answers if they are not tested. Patrick for example then fixed his and it is fine. But the others are incorrect answers....

Answer (score 2):

> I think Temm[i][j] maybe illegal

Yes it is. use `[i,j]` instead.

> I also wanted to know how to declare the given size of the two
>   dimensional List

Correct way is:

```
List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i=0; i<A.Count; i++)
{
    Temm[i] = new List<double>();
  //Your code
```

Comment: `Temm[i][j]` is not illegal. you are probably thinking of a multidimensional array, in which case `Temm[i, j]` would be the correct way to access an item.

Comment: @Aditya - the `[i][j]` is fine - and also the `[i,j]` is fine - they are different things. And about the suggestion - have you checked it that it is working?

Answer (score 1):

For arrays, use `[i,j]`

For lists, initialize all elements of the outer list.

```
List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>();
for (var i=0; i<i_max; i++)
    Temm.Add( new List<double>() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Temm[i][j] is not illegal. In this case with lists it's the only way to access an item of an inner list without using a variable in between. `Temm[i][j]` is equivalent to `var temmInner = Temm[i]; ... temmInner[j] ...`

You can only use `[i, j]` if you have a multidimensional array, as opposed to an array of arrays (or list of lists in your code).

You can't declare the size of a `List`. At best you can give it a starting capacity (which will increase when you add more items to the list)

One bug I see in your code is that you never add new lists to `Temm` so I would suggest to change your code to:

```
List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
{
    Temm.Add(new List<double>());
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].Count; j++)
    {
        double temmValue;
        if (A[i][j] != 0) { temmValue = A[i][j]; }
        else { temmValue = Temm[i][j - 1]; }
        Temm[i].Add(temmValue)
    }
}
```

btw some very suspect code is `if (A[i][j] != 0) { ... } else { ... Temm[i][j - 1]; }` You are now depending on the fact the the first item of an inner `A` list is never 0. It's probably a good idea to check `j == 0` as well.

Comment: Sure, I just make the simplicity of my code. So, the most general way of the `List` for `loop` is using the `add`?

Comment: Yes, using `Add` would be the most general way of adding items. In this case you could also change my new line to `List<double> temmInner = new List<double>(); Temm.Add(temmInner);` and replace all `Temm[i][j] = ...` with `temmInner.Add(...)` you would still need to use the indexer to get an item though. So at best you could replace `Temm[i][j - 1]` with `temmInner[j - 1]`

Comment: @GiladGreen You are right. I somehow had in mind you could add items with the indexer at index == Count. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<List<double>> Temm = new List<List<double>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
        {
            Temm.Add(A[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < A[i].Count; j++)
            {
                if (A[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    Temm[i][j] = A[i][j];
                }
                else
                {
                    Temm[i][j] = Temm[i][j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
```