# convert from list[] to two dimensional object[,] array [C#]

Tags: c#

I pull csv data using `StreamReader` into a `List<string[]>`, which I then want to convert to a two dimensional array in order to extract data into another similar array using logical rules with looping (I want to be able to access [row,column] data individually). Here is the csv method:

```
    public static object[] CsvData(string filePath)
    {
        List<string[]> csvContent = new List<string[]>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] lineArr = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                csvContent.Add(lineArr);
            }
        }
        return csvContent.ToArray();
    }
```

Currently my object array output is one dimensional. I have tried modifying it in various ways but can't get the dimensions to add up to give me a `object[,]` on the return. I am using object arrays since the data has more than one type.

Comment: What sort of access can you get from a two-dimensional array that you can't get with a `List<string[]>`? Zero-based indexers work with both `List` and `string[]`.

Comment: what is the purpose of this `Row++;`?

Comment: After converting it to an object arrays all elements in the arrays are still strings. You only lose the knowlegde of it. Converting to a specific type has to be done per element

Comment: @ZevSpitz, honestly I just have not used Lists up to now and have not needed the added functionality over and above what a VBA excel array(,) gives you. Array also seems more basic, at least in syntax.

Comment: @reds thanks, did not need that in there

Comment: @ZevSpitz I can't find an example showing the ease of using a basic array with Lists, again the syntax seems overly complicated: `List<List<object>>` , [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073502/c-sharp-for-loop-of-two-dimensional-list]

Comment: The declaration of the type is perhaps a little more complex than you are used to, but reading/writing element to a `List<string[]>` -- `var item = csvContext[row][col];` is almost the same as the indexer access for a two-dimensional array -- `var item = arr[row,col];`.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
var rows = csvContent.Count - 1;
var cols = csvContent.Max(x => x.Length + 1);
string[,] arr = new string[rows,cols];
foreach (var (x,index) in csvContent.SelectMany(x => x).Select((x,index) => (x,index))) {
    var row = index / cols;
    var col = index % cols;
    arr[row,col] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
 public static List<object[]> CsvData()
        {
            List<object[]> csvContent = new List<object[]>();

              ///Code here
            return csvContent;
        }
```

or

```
  public static List<string[]> CsvData()
        {
            List<string[]> csvContent = new List<string[]>();

              ///Code here
            return csvContent;
        }
```